# Dataframe.isin is not working for me, returns same no of rows even if there are intersecting rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, isin

I am applying an inner join in a for loop on another dataset and now I just need to remove the rows that are already part of the inner join so I went with Dataframe.isin(another_df) but it is not giving me the expected results. I checked the column names and their data types, they are all the same. Can someone help me with that, please?

In the following code, isin is where I check between two data frames still I'm not getting any response, I'm getting the same set of rows even if they have the same no of rows and columns.
Note: I'm dropping an extra column in isin function as it is the extra column present in one of the dataframes.
My code looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= override.columns)

for i in list1:
    join_value = tuple(i)
    i.append('creditor_tier_interim')
    subset_df = override.merge(criteria[i].dropna(), on = list(join_value), how = 'inner')
    subset_df['PRE_CHARGEOFF_FLAG'] = pd.to_numeric(subset_df.PRE_CHARGEOFF_FLAG)
    override=override[~override.isin(subset_df.drop(columns = 'creditor_tier_interim'))].dropna(how = 'all')
    print('The override shape would be:', override.shape)
    df = df.append(subset_df)
df = df.append(override)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have 'left' and a 'right' DataFrames and you're look for those records that are exclusively in one or the other. The below returns rows that are in exclusively the right or left DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

dataframe_left = DataFrame(np.random.randn(25).reshape(5,5),columns=['A','B','C','D','E'],index=np.arange(5))
dataframe_right = DataFrame(np.random.randn(25).reshape(5,5),columns=['A','B','C','D','E'],index=np.arange(5))

insert_left = DataFrame(np.arange(5).reshape(1,5),columns=['A','B','C','D','E'],index=[7])
insert_right = DataFrame(np.arange(5).reshape(1,5),columns=['A','B','C','D','E'], index=[6])

dataframe_right = dataframe_right.append(insert_right)
dataframe_left = dataframe_left.append(insert_left)
```

Code above produces this output

**Left Table**

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.3240086903973736 | 1.0441549453943946 | -0.23640436950107843 | 0.5466767470739027 | -0.2123693649877372 |
| 1 | -0.04263388410830733 | -0.4855492977594353 | -1.5584284407735072 | 1.2438524586306603 | -0.31087239909921277 |
| 2 | 0.6982581750529829 | -0.42379154444215905 | 1.1625089013522614 | -3.378898146269229 | 1.0550121763954057 |
| 3 | 0.3774337535208665 | 0.6402576096348337 | -0.2787520258645991 | 0.31071767629270125 | 0.34499495360962007 |
| 4 | -0.133649590435452 | 0.3679768579635411 | -2.0196709364730014 | 1.2860033685128436 | -0.49674737879741193 |
| 7 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |

**Right Table**

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.09946693056759418 | -0.03378933704588447 | -0.4117873368048701 | 0.21976489856531914 | -0.7020527418892488 |
| 1 | -2.9936183481793233 | 0.42443360961021837 | -0.1681576564885903 | -0.5080538565354785 | -0.29483296271514153 |
| 2 | -0.6567306172004121 | -1.221239625798079 | -1.2604670988941196 | 0.44472543746187265 | -0.4562966381137614 |
| 3 | -0.0027697712245823482 | 0.1323767897141191 | -0.11073953230359104 | -0.3596157927825233 | 1.9894525572891626 |
| 4 | 0.5170901011452596 | -1.1694605240821456 | 0.29238712582282705 | -0.38912521589557797 | -0.8793074660039492 |
| 6 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |

After setting up the test dataframes we can join the two and filter for the rows we're interested in:

```
tmp = pd.merge(
  left=dataframe_left,
  right=dataframe_right,
  right_index=True,
  left_index=True,
  how='outer',
  suffixes=['_left','_right'],
  indicator=True
)

tmp[tmp._merge.isin(['right_only','left_only'])]
```

This produces the below result

|  | A_left | B_left | C_left | D_left | E_left | A_right | B_right | C_right | D_right | E_right | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | right_only |
| 7 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |  |  |  |  |  | left_only |

Comment: Thank you for this, but this method would be a little tricky if I have to check for the intersection of rows in left and right in an iterative loop for my left table being consistent since each time I'll have to consider the uniqueness of the final table. Can I do something in the iterative loop?